# Amplify: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing error even though CORS is enabled in API Gateway and Lambda headers

Tags: cors, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-vue

I'm using Amplify, and have my API Gateway proxying to Lambda. I've enabled CORS on my `/{proxy+}` and deployed the API. In my Lambda function, I'm setting the appropriate header in my trivial function:

```py
import json


def handler(event, context):
    print("received event:")
    print(event)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        "body": json.dumps(event),
    }
```

This Lambda function sits behind an API Gateway resource which is authenticated via Cognito.

When I invoke my API using Amplify:

```js
let myInit = {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
              .getIdToken()
              .getJwtToken()}`
          }
        }; 

API.get("adminapi", "/admin", myInit) ...
```

I get the dreaded CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing from my `GET` request:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/admin. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

I see it returned in the `OPTIONS` request:

[image]

I even tested in Postman to verify the headers are coming back:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? It doesn't look like the call is getting past API Gateway. I wonder if it has to do with authentication. When I test from Postman using my IAM credentials it works fine, but from my web app using the bearer token it fails as above.

Comment: Always quote the **full** error message. I suspect it says that the header is missing from the preflight response and not the requested resource.

Comment: Header is missing from the GET request. The OPTIONS request works just fine.

Comment: Updated question to include more details.

Comment: Did you ever found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 8):

I've just struggled with something similar. The question here asks why the browser is returning a CORS errors when hitting API Gateway with Amplify despite CORS headers being configured correctly in the endpoint.

Aside from incorrect CORS header config, Amplify / API Gateway gives a CORS error if certain aspects of the request are incorrect. The ones I've comes across are:

- The HTTP verb you are using does not exist against the endpoint
- The endpoint you are using doesn't exist (e.g. a typo)
- The Content-Type header is incorrect

The latter was causing me issues. It seems that `Amplify.API.post` and `Amplify.API.put` both send a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. My API was expecting `application/json` and the result was a CORS error.

Answer (score 1):

When using `fetch()` in js when I removed the Cognito Authentication from my API Gateway OPTIONS endpoints it worked. Chrome and Firefox don't send the Authorize headers to OPTIONS. Might be different with amplify though. Quoting: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses ...

```
"For a CORS-preflight request, request’s credentials mode is always "same-origin", i.e., it excludes credentials, but for any subsequent CORS requests it might not be."
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you forgot to handle the `OPTIONS` verb that's used for the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and return the header there.

You are sending an `Authorization` header, which is not in the list of allowed headers for ["simple" requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), hence a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) is done.

Furthermore, in order for [credentials to get through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials), you have to ensure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header is set as well.

It's not apparent from the code snippet what content type your request body is, but if it's anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` (say, `application/json`), you also need to whitelist the `Content-Type` header using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`.

Comment: `OPTIONS` is being handled (somewhere) because it returns `access-control-allow-origin: *`. I updated my function to include `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True` in the response headers. Same situation. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is set in API Gateway by default as `'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'`.

Comment: What happens if you put Fiddler in between? Check what actually goes over the line and how it differs from your tests. Maybe you are getting an error in your server (invalid authentication for example) which then won't return those headers (because it seems you only return them in the success case with status 200)? Maybe your authorization header is not sent because your library doesn't pass `withCredentials: true` to the XHR...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. My pre-flight `OPTIONS` request had all of the correct headers:

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

So the browser started to accept requests after I added

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

To the  response of the requests of the actual method I wanted to use (the non-preflight, eg: the `GET`, `POST`,etc method)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem pop up for me where I was working with Amplify and trying to secure the API Gateway to only be accessible to logged in users via Cognito.

The step that I had missed which you may have also missed is a bit of configuration within AWS API-Gateway. You need to go to the Gateway dashboard and create an 'Authorizer' which uses your Cognito User Pool. The `token source` is going to be whatever header label you are using for this (usually 'Authorization').

[image: Creating new Authorizer]

But you are not quite done. You then need to go to 'Resources' and change the Method Request to use your new Authorizer that you just created.

[image: Using the new Authorizer with the resources]

Hopefully after doing all this, you should be fine. If your user is logged in, and you add the Authorization header as you had:

```js
let myInit = {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
              .getIdToken()
              .getJwtToken()}`
          }
        };
```

Then hopefully it all works out.

A video guide showing these steps can be found on [here on Youtube, and starting around 10:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs9HfYbWjXQ&t=652s)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is getting the same CORS error process as me: the preflight request was successful, and you configure everything with the '*' and the response headers allowed everything, but your actual request still got error. Please try to delete the AdminQueries api and its Lambda function and add everything again

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error with AWS AMPLIFY then please check your Amplify configuration file.

1. You might be missing identityPoolId if yes then add identityPoolId
   in your configuration.
2. if identityPoolId is present then make sure that it is the correct one.

It is so because AWS AMPLIFY does not sign the request if idenitityPoolId is missing or incorrect.

I faced a similar issue and resolved my issue by this approach. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

In case it helps anyone: our team fixed this by adding scope `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` to Cognito Auth provider settings.

Comment: Please could you provide some screenshot or guidance?